# Django 4.0 shows path not found even after configuring all urls and views properly

Tags: python, django

So my django app looks like this

```
-assaydash
--dashboard (app)
--members (app)
--djangobackend (django project directory)
--static
--manage.py
```

`djangobackend/settings.py`

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'dashboard.apps.DashboardConfig',
    'members.apps.MembersConfig',
]
```

`djangobackend/urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin'),
    path('', include('dashboard.urls')),
    path('members/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('members/', include('members.urls')),   
]
```

`members/urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login_user', views.login_user, name="login"),
    path('logout_user', views.logout_user, name='logout'),
]
```

`members/views.py`

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        ...
        else:
            messages.success(request, ("There Was An Error Logging In, Try Again..."))  
            return redirect('login')    


    else:
        return render(request, 'authenticate/login.html', {})

def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
    messages.success(request, ("You Were Logged Out!"))
    return redirect('home')
```

`index.html`

```
 <a href="{% url 'login' %}" >
    <span class="d-sm-inline d-none">Sign In</span>
 </a>
```

On the index page when i click on the a tag it shows me a debug page with path not found. Even though the url exists and i have included it in my main urls.py and i have added the app in the settings.py as well. please help and let me know what is wrong here.
Notice that the url for name `login` was detected by the template but the path wasn't found. Also the other urls on the debug page are from my dashboard app which works fine
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because you have set the `url` path of `django.contrib.auth.urls` to `members/` and the `django.contrib.auth.urls` include `patterns` of `/members/login/` for `name=login`. Since `urlpatterns` will look from upper to lower your `/members/login/` called instead of `/members/login_user`and look for `corresponding` page. So change your `url` path to others than `members/` in

```
path('members/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

and use `members/` for `include('members.urls')`.

If you have set

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

]

The `django.contrib.auth.urls` include `urlpatterns` as

```
accounts/login/ [name='login']
accounts/logout/ [name='logout']
accounts/password_change/ [name='password_change']
accounts/password_change/done/ [name='password_change_done']
accounts/password_reset/ [name='password_reset']
accounts/password_reset/done/ [name='password_reset_done']
accounts/reset/<uidb64>/<token>/ [name='password_reset_confirm']
accounts/reset/done/ [name='password_reset_complete']
```

See [**Authentication Views[Django-doc]**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views)

So change your `djangobackend/urls.py` as

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin'),
    path('', include('dashboard.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('members/', include('members.urls')),   
]
```

Also change your member `urls.py` as

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login_user', views.login_user, name="login-user"),
    path('logout_user', views.logout_user, name='logout-user'),
]
```

Also in `html`

```
<a href="{% url 'login-user' %}" >
    <span class="d-sm-inline d-none">Sign In</span>
 </a>
```

Comment: i Tried this and i still get the same error. I have previously tried commenting out the line where i defined url for django.contrib.auth.urls but i still get the same path not found